# Unable to launch puppeteer on local - Mac M1

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have installed puppeteer using brew. Also, I have puppeteer as a dependency in my project.

But when my code reaches on this line:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
```

It throws this error in the terminal:
[image]

I am not able to find solution anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try once with this

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({  
          headless: headless,
          defaultViewport: null,
          executablePath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
      });
```

Assuming you have chrome and its executable is at the location i mentioned you can find the same for you by typing chrome://version in your chrome browser

probably some issue with the way you installed chromium

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much.
So why it was not able to find the path by default ? And what should I do so that I do not have to pass this executable path in future ?

Comment: can you execute which chromium and share the output for the same, also can you share how you installed puppeteer for this project

Answer (score 3):

To use Puppeteer's Chromium on an M1 Mac you need to have Rosetta 2 installed.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Comment: "Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported."

Comment: this works for me

Comment: This worked for me! Initially it threw an error saying `Fatal error: spawn Unknown system error -86` but after running this command on the terminal and installing rosetta, it worked. 

Why doesn't apple enable rosetta out of the box for everyone?